# Add shiping cost on add product page

Tags: rules, commerce

Can some one please tell how it is possible to add the shipping prices from Add Product Page. Actually I want to add the field on product page where the store admin can define the rates for each specific product type.

Comment: Please specify whether you're using Shipping 1.x or 2.x. They require separate solutions (both start with a price field on products, but diverge on plugin VS module/rule).

Comment: its Shipping 7.x-2.0-beta1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a module that does this!

https://drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_field

It allows you to define a shipping cost for each individual product. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: there is no download link available on that page.

Comment: It's a sandbox, so you have to check out the git repository under 'version control'. Just do this in your modules folder:

git clone --branch 7.x-1.x http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/rerooting/2104243.git commerce_shipping_rate_field

Comment: I just released the module as stable, so try it now if you are using the UI or FTP to install modules.  There were a few bugfixes so you will need to update anyways.

Comment: nice to hear that. I will definitely give that a try and revert back to you

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [Ubercart global quote](http://drupal.org/project/uc_global_quote)

Ubercart Shipping quote module that provides custom shipping quotes based on configurable weight ranges and custom shipping zones.

Comment: The poster specified that he's using Drupal Commerce, not Ubercart.

Comment: Woops, my bad. Sorry poster, If you decided to switch to ubercart here is my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This was possible in Shipping 1.0 for Drupal Commerce 1.3. You can see more information about this on a post I did in Drupal.org here http://drupal.org/node/1778566.

1. What you need to do is create the shipping price field on your products and set the value of shipping per items.
2. Next you need to create a plugin for checking the cost of shipping via that field.
3. Voila you are done.

Hint: The code in that link can be used exactly for your project...